# Is there a Scala way of selecting a subset of List[Array[Int]] by checking each element of each Array[Int]?

Tags: list, scala, nested-lists, traversal

New to Scala. I have data of the form List[Array[Int]],each Array[Int] has n integers, call this a. There are also two Array[int], call them c and d, also of length n. I want to compare each element of each row of a to the corresponding element of c and d (i.e, of same index) and return those rows that match c or d.

Nothing at stake here, just self teaching Scala.

Comment: First of all, your title says `List[List[Int]]` in the title and then you start talking about Arrays. They are very different types to a point that the equality mechanics actually work differently on two. Can you please clarify the actual type you have? 

Then your title says you want to check the first element of the list only to proceed to say you want to compare each element of each row. That doesn't add up.

Please revise the question accordingly

Comment: Edited title. I thought List and Arrays would be the same, especially using sameElements.

Comment: Scala directly uses the Java Arrays. They are treated specially by the JVM for performance reasons among others. Lists are a language level construct. Are `c` and `d` also of length `n`?

Comment: Yes, edited text to reflect that they are of length n.

Comment: That's fine. Nothing for with trying different approaches. In fact that's encouraged :)   If they are guaranteed to be the same length, then you are simply looking to filter for the rows that are equal to `c` or `d`.  In that case, if I am not missing anything something like `x.filter(a => a.sameElements(c) || a.sameElements(d))` should work.  You can read about `filter` in the [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#filter(p:A=%3EBoolean):List[A])

Comment: I would recommend using `List`, `Vector` or `ArraySeq` instead of plain `Arrays`

Comment: @sinanspd Thanks. Will give it a try and read about filter. Will comment on here if further questions, if that’s ok.

Comment: +1 on Luis' comment. In addition I would like to invite you to join the [Scala discord](https://discord.gg/pnQ3XC88). It is better suited for extended discussions. Stackoverflow is more for open and shut answers.  In any case, the docs should always be the first thing you check before asking a question. They very often have the answer

Comment: Ok. Works, but I might have misunderstood the problem. I have one question: how do I go about creating a subset of a where all rows are shortened by one, with the first removed, make a new comparison with a similarly shrunk c and d, and keep doing it till n shrinks to 1? [reason i am asking: the content of c and d depend on a, so if a shrinks with head removed, d and c change accordingly.

Comment: @Tico it would be better to re-ask that question in the discord sever and try to be clearer, adding an example would help.

Comment: Yep. Let's either take this to discord or open a new question. Remember that other people in the future will look at your question. They shouldn't need to read through a bunch of comments not related to the original question. One question, one post.

Comment: Ok. Thank you both. I'll try and prep a question tomorrow, if the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this starting point:

```scala
val c = Array(1,2,3)
val d = Array(0,1,2)
val target: List[Array[Int]] = List(c,d)

val as: List[Array[Int]] =
  List(
    Array(0,1,2),
    Array(1,2,3),
    Array(2,3,4),
    Array(4,5,6),
  )
```

Here is how to get only the arrays from `as` that match exactly `c` or `d`:

```scala
as
  .filter(a => a.sameElements(c) || a.sameElements(d))


//and a bit more generic if you have a big target pool
as
  .filter(a => target.exists(_.sameElements(a)))
```

This solution is resilient to possible empty or different sizes arrays in `as`.

Answer (score 0):

There are different way for tackle this problem, a possible approach could be using `.zip`

For example:

```scala
val a = List(Array(1,1,1), Array(2,2,2), Array(3,3,3)) 
val c = Array(2,2,2) 

val res = a.map(arr => arr.zip(c))
```

Into the res you will have something like

```
/*
List[Array[Tuple2[Int, Int]]] = List(
  Array((1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2)),
  Array((2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2)),
  Array((3, 2), (3, 2), (3, 2))
)
*
```

With this structure is pretty easy compare each elements, for example

```
res.map(arr => arr.map(e => e._1 == e._2)) 
/*
res1: List[Array[Boolean]] = List(
  Array(false, false, false),
  Array(true, true, true),
  Array(false, false, false)
)
*/
```